# Highcharts: Dynamic drilldown (stacked chart) in Combo Dual Axes

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Well I have this issue, this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/1/

has you can see, when I clicked in a column I change to a stacked chart, but sometimes I will have 3 columns, 5, etc, my question is, exists a way to detect this?

```
if (drilldown) { 
     setChart([drilldown.name, drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2, drilldown.name3, drilldown.name4, drilldown.name5],  drilldown.categories,  [drilldown.data, drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2, drilldown.data3, drilldown.data4, drilldown.data5], drilldown.color, [drilldown.type]); 
}
```

Another thing that I cant resolve yet is, why I can't get the name in the drilldown for the legends and the tooltip? And can I formatter the tooltip for the drilldown?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change from data1, data2, data3 etc. to this:

```
                data:[[
                    {name:'Recomendación',y:17},
                    {name:'Recomendación',y:20},
                    {name:'Recomendación',y:50}
                ],[
                    {name:'Area de Oportunidad',y:3},
                    {name:'Area de Oportunidad',y:0},
                    {name:'Area de Oportunidad',y:3}
                ],[
                    {name:'Observación',y:1},
                    {name:'Observación',y:1},
                    {name:'Observación',y:2}
                ]],
```

Then in setChart use:

```
setChart([drilldown.name, drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2, drilldown.name3, drilldown.name4, drilldown.name5],  drilldown.categories,  drilldown.data, drilldown.color, [drilldown.type]);
```

2) Do the same for names.

Comment: I made the changes that you told me, but the lengends still not working and its not taking the names of the drilldowns, and in the column 3 doesn´t show the name of the column dunno why :/ Can I set shared true in tooltip when is stacked? http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/4/

Comment: Well this is my final jsfiddle, jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/7 thank you ^^! Only think I cant modified was the color in the legend, don't know how or why is in black.

Comment: Because you are passing only one color. After previous changes in `data`, you have `colors: colors[0]`, change it to `color:colors` and then in `setChart` change `color:color || 'white'` to `color:color[i] || 'white'`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/8/ (first column)